How to rotate/flip faces of a mesh after split edges with geometry nodes?
I'm trying to animate the faces to flip (180 degrees) from front to backside of a mesh with geometry nodes.
I have tried this setup (and others) but can't get it to work. Can someone please help me in the right direction, thanx.


In order to flip a face, where flip means rotating by 180°, and end up with the mesh looking the same way afterwards, you need to find a line of symmetry to rotate around. For icosphere's equilateral triangles, any height (line between center of base and corner above it) will do. Since only direction of this vector matters, you don't need to find center of an edge, as all heights go through center of the face. Therefore taking the offset between the center of the face and any corner will give you a valid rotation axis for the icosphere's tris:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

wow, much simpler than my setup

@Crantisz Yea I'm lazy

Evaluate on domain instead of capture attribute will make it more clear.

Thank you so much, really learning here.

Thanx again for your setup, beginning to understand, I'm struggling with getting the axis. How would you get the Axis of a face from let say a low poly model (suzanne monkey)?

@dcvz not all triangles are symmetric... You can cheat and deform the triangle while you're rotating it, but the solution will be different than for an icosphere.

How would you get the axis of a face from a UV Sphere or torus or any other mesh (that's made up of squares)? Is the normal an option?

@dcvz for UV sphere's quads (those aren't squares!) you could find the offset between the center of first horizontal edge and the center of 2nd horizontal edge. However UV sphere also has triangles and for these you would do as in my answer but specifically pick the pole vertex rather than any vertex. For a torus you could sort edges by how much they span in the angle around torus' center, and take those parallel with radii to do the same as with horizontal edges with a UV sphere... Any other mesh: again, you're not guaranteed to work with symmetric triangles or quads!

Well, you have to specify axis and rotation center.


It is quite easy with center. Just calculate the center for each mesh island:

For axis, it is quite hard, because it involves topology nodes. For each triangle, subtract one vertex from the center of two others to get axis:


Thank you for you setup and explanation.
